# use of synchronized method in affable bean shopping cart

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, synchronized

having a look at the netbeans affable bean tutorial. Why do we need the use of synchronized methods here?

```
public synchronized int getNumberOfItems() {

        numberOfItems = 0;

        for (ShoppingCartItem scItem : items) {

            numberOfItems += scItem.getQuantity();
        }

        return numberOfItems;
    }


    public synchronized double getSubtotal() {

        double amount = 0;

        for (ShoppingCartItem scItem : items) {

            Product product = (Product) scItem.getProduct();
            amount += (scItem.getQuantity() * product.getPrice().doubleValue());
        }

        return amount;
    }
```

Comment: sample code is found here http://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/content/samples/javaee/AffableBean/src/java/cart/ShoppingCart.java?rev=77

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like every method related to the ShoppingCartItems management is synchronized. Certainly to prevent a concurrent access in the *items* List (`List<ShoppingCartItem> items;`).

Without the synchronized, you could have 1+ Thread accessing a 'read' method such as `getSubtotal ()` while the `items` List is being updated through public `synchronized void addItem(Product product)` by another Thread.

The source can be found [here](http://netbeans.org/projects/samples/sources/samples-source-code/content/samples/javaee/AffableBean/src/java/cart/ShoppingCart.java?rev=77)

Comment: could you be more explicit? maybe a real world example related to the affable bean cart. is it a concurrency issue or real time transaction issue?

Comment: @devilived Without it, you'd get concurrency issue. Unlike a 'real' cart, you can't load your cart and unload it at the same time. You can encounter an inconsistency while doing so that's why it will trigger an Exception and you need that synchronized keyword here.

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you may shop using two different windows and the cart must be updated properly, so all related methods are marked as `synchronized`